# Concatenating two fields in LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation

I have a dropdownlist, ddCourse, that I'm populating with the following LINQ query:

```
var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
ddCourse.DisplayMember = "COURSE_TITLE";
ddCourse.ValueMember = "COURSE_ID";
ddCourse.DataSource = db.COURSE_MASTERs.OrderBy(c => c.COURSE_TITLE)
                                       .Select(c => new { c.COURSE_ID, c.COURSE_TITLE })
                                       .ToList();
```

There's another field, though, that I'd like to concatenate to the COURSE_TITLE field in my selection.  So, I'd like my selection to look like:

```
.Select( c => new {c.COURSE_ID, c.CIN + " " + c.COURSE_TITLE})
```

The only problem is that this, apparently, isn't how it's done.  I'm basically wanting to join c.CIN with c.COURSE_TITLE (and have a space in the middle).  Can someone offer me some pointers on how to accomplish this?

The reason I want to do this is that, right now, the only thing appearing in the dropdownlist is the course title.  I'd like to have the course ID number (CIN) concatenated to it when it displays.

EDIT: For clarification, I'm using Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: It's always important to mention any exception messages you get and also what flavor of LINQ you're working with (linq-to-sql I guess?).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use this

```
.Select( c => new {c.COURSE_ID, COURSE_TITLE =string.Format("{0} {1}" ,c.CIN ,c.COURSE_TITLE)})
```

Comment: I think string.Format will only work if the objects are already loaded into memory. I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure Entity Framework will choke on that, and the posted code looks like it might be EF.

Comment: How about for `OrderBy`?

Comment: Simple and Great !

Comment: How can I convert this to string array

Answer (score 6):

You need to name your [anonymous members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

```
.Select( c => new {COURSE_ID = c.COURSE_ID, COURSE_TITLE = c.CIN + " " + c.COURSE_TITLE})
```

Comment: This solution worked for me in LINQ to Entities where `string.Format` would not. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Write your `Select` like this:

```
.Select( c => new {c.COURSE_ID, COURSE_TITLE = c.CIN + " " + c.COURSE_TITLE})
```

Anonymous types need to have their column names specified, in case they cannot be inferred.

For `c.COURSE_ID` C# is smart enough to generate a member called `COURSE_ID` in the anonymous type. For the expression `c.CIN + " " + c.COURSE_TITLE` it cannot.